# Non standard evaluation, lapply, and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse

I'm trying to programmatically plot distributions using ggplot2.

I can't figure out how to work with non standard evaluation (NSE) here (even after having read Hadley's book chapter etc. on NSE).

Consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)


gg_dens <- function(x){
  eval(ggplot(data.frame(x), aes_string(x = substitute(x))) + geom_density() +
         ggtitle(substitute(x)), data.frame(x))
}


lapply(mtcars, function(x) gg_dens(x))
```

This code *does* produce a number of density plots, one for each column, ok. However, it does **not** print the name of the variable being plotted. Rather, the placeholder variable `x` is printed (cf. figure).

[image: plot resulting from code above]

My goal is to have the `x` quote substituted by the real variable name, eg., `mpg`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but does not work for me

Comment: are you just experimenting (i.e. is this a learning exercise)? if not, `aes_string()` helps with variable subst greatly.

Comment: `x` (in the lapply loop) is an unnamed atomic vector. It doesn't have a name to be used with `substitute`.

Comment: Is it not better to define function as `gg_dens <- function(myData, myCol){...}` then use `aes_string` for `myCol`, and also use `myCol` for plot title?

Comment: following @zx8754 comment. you can try something like `mapply(gg_dens, df, colnames(df))` while the function is defined as `gg_dens <- function(data, title){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` is not going to work with the function you have right now to solve this. `x` is simply a vector when passed to that function, it is not the name of that variable, and `lapply` isn't passing anything that *is* the name. In other words, there is nothing in the scope of that function for it to figure out what should be the proper x-axis label.

One solution is similar to @Jimbou:

```
gg_dens <- function(name, dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes_string(x = name)) + geom_density() + ggtitle(name)
}    
lapply(names(mtcars), gg_dens, mtcars)
```

Or just use facets instead:

```
mtcars2 <- tidyr::gather(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(value)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free')
```

Comment: Thanks @Axeman, that solved the issue. And I now understand NSE and ggplot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
gg_dens <- function(x, y){
  ggplot(y, aes_(x = as.name(colnames(y)[x]))) + geom_density() + ggtitle(colnames(y)[x])
}

lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), gg_dens, mtcars)
```

The idea is to loop through the column index. The `aes_` convert strings to names together with `as.name`.